# sort array of pointers to structures qsort

Tags: c, pointers, qsort

I'm trying to sort an array of pointers to structures where the key to compare is one of the structure's property.

I think that probably is the compare method.

Here's an example code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD {
    char *name;
};

int compare(const void *node1, const void *node2) {
    return strcmp(
        ((struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD *) node1)->name,
        ((struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD *) node2)->name
    );
}

int main()
{
    struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD **records;

    records = malloc(sizeof(struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD *) * 2);

    records[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD));
    records[1] = malloc(sizeof(struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD));

    records[0]->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen("string2") + 1));
    records[1]->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen("string1") + 1));

    strcpy(records[0]->name, "string2");
    strcpy(records[1]->name, "string1");

    qsort(records, 2, sizeof(records[0]), compare);

    printf("%s\n", records[0]->name);
    printf("%s\n", records[1]->name);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess this should be simpler..

```
  int compare(const void *node1, const void *node2) {
      BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD *ptr1 = *(BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD * const *)node1;
      BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD *ptr2 = *(BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD * const *)node2;
      return strcmp(ptr1->name, ptr2->name);
    }
```

And also I think the qsort function call could be definitely right if it were something like this,

```
qsort(records, 2, sizeof(BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD*), compare);
```

I think the third argument must be the size of the structure and you can be definitely be sure if it were something like the above..

Comment: struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD **records

so records[0] its the same as struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD *

Comment: I thought it was ok the first answer but when i try with more than 2 pointers on the array fails. the correct answer is that gave me Ajai. I edit a little to get rid of the variables.

int compare(const void *node1, const void *node2) {
 return strcmp(
  (*(struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD * const *) node1)->name,
  (*(struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD * const *) node2)->name
 );
}

Comment: why? the subscript operator dereferer from struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD ** to struct BINARY_ARRAY_RECORD *