# C qsort doesn't sort structure arrays

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, structure

I have a program that's designed to read in words and split them apart, separating each and counting them up individually (words with punctuation differences are counted as different words on purpose).

```
typedef struct word
{
    char letters[100];
    int count;
} Word;

int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return strcmp((*(struct word **) a)->letters,(*(struct word **) b)->letters);
}

int main()
{
    int sizeCheck = 0;
    Word ** collection = malloc(sizeof(Word*));
    Word * array = malloc(sizeof(Word));

    FILE *fptr, *fout;
    char fileName[80];
    char fileNameWords[80];
    char wordLine[100];
    strcpy(fileName,"data");
    strcpy(fileNameWords,fileName);
    strcat(fileNameWords,"data.out.txt");
```

Where the action starts, assuming everything's fine with opening files (removed for shortness sake):

```
            int wordExists = 0;
            int t1 = 0;
            char tw1[100];


            fscanf(fptr,"%s",wordLine);
            strcpy(array->letters,wordLine);
            array->count = 1;
            collection[sizeCheck] = array;
            sizeCheck++;

            while (!feof(fptr))
            {
                wordExists = 0;
                fscanf(fptr,"%s",wordLine);
                for (t1 = 0; (t1 < sizeCheck) && (wordExists == 0); t1++)
                {
                    strcpy(tw1,array[t1].letters);
                    if (strcmp(tw1,wordLine) == 0)
                    {
                        array[t1].count += 1;
                        wordExists = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (!wordExists)
                {
                    collection = realloc(collection,(sizeCheck+1)*sizeof(Word*));
                    array = realloc(array,(sizeCheck+1)*sizeof(Word));
                    strcpy(array[sizeCheck].letters,wordLine);
                    array[sizeCheck].count = 1;
                    collection[sizeCheck] = array;
                    sizeCheck++;
                }
            }

            qsort(collection,sizeCheck,sizeof(Word*),compare);

            for (t1 = 0; t1 < sizeCheck; t1++)
            {
                fprintf(fout,"%s - %d\n",array[t1].letters,array[t1].count);
            }
            free(collection);
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

Using a pointer-to-pointer method, it works for the most part, except when it comes to either the qsort function, or the fprintf parts near the bottom. I'm a little stumped at this point. What am I doing wrong here that's preventing this from outputting a sorted file? (Sorting by alphabetical order with words)

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451020/sort-array-of-pointers-to-structures-qsort?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the `collection` array (an array of pointers) is being sorted. The values they point to (the elements of `array`) are unchanged. Since you `fprintf` the elements of `array`, you won't see any changes.

If you want to sort `array`, you can do that with `qsort`:

```
qsort(array, sizeCheck, sizeof(Word), compareWord);
```

where `compareWord` is

```
int compareWord(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const Word *wa = a;
    const Word *wb = b;
    return strcmp(a->letters, b->letters);
}
```

Alternately, just print out the elements from `collection` instead of `array`:

```
fprintf(fout, "%s - %d\n", collection[t1]->letters, collection[t1]->count);
```